# Reasonable price for getting doors repainted?

Tags: paint

I know this isn't the most on topic question, but I don't know where else to get good advice.

I recently got my Jeep's doors stolen.  My insurance gave my a check for $2550, so I bought some half doors on craigslist ($600) and some really nice custom made windows ($800).

When I went to the local body shop and asked for a quote in getting the two parts (four items in total) painted, they said it was going to run me $800.

This is after I told them that I would remove all components not to be painted from the metal door frame, and the window that I ordered comes disassembled already - meaning the body shop does not have to take anything apart, or even tape it off.

I'm worried that they just looked at the insurance stub, and thought that they could take advantage of my by pretty much filling the difference in what my insurance company gave me and what I have already spent.

Here's a picture of the two items that I am getting painted, again, I am going to give them to the shop ready to paint.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Pricing assistance is off topic. If you'd like to discuss this in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/general-discussion), I'm sure we could provide some assistance there :D

Comment: For clarity, the chat is found here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/general-discussion  Open ended discussions are welcome there.